# How to fix - configuration error: `project` must contain ['name'] properties in pyproject.toml?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, pyproject.toml

Specifications

```
Apple M1 chip processor
Python 3.9.6
setuptools==65.3.0
virtualenv==20.23.1
pipenv===2023.4.29
```

pyproject.toml file at project's root directory

```
[project]
name = 'project name'
requires-python = ">=3.9"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = [
    {name = "Your Name", email = "you@yourdomain.com"},
]
```

When I try to import package from a private repository, it gives error -

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         File "/private/var/folders/xf/w00tn6c94kggl81pbhysxs300000gp/T/pip-build-env-2jhqtx43/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/pyprojecttoml.py", line 55, in validate
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:           raise ValueError(f"{error}\n{summary}") from None
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       ValueError: invalid pyproject.toml config: `project`.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       configuration error: `project` must contain ['name'] properties
```

Can someone please help how to fix this?
Also why is are the files in private folder being referenced here?

I tried to update to latest version of setuptools and added the following in pyproject.toml file

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools==65.3.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

But, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have anything else in your `pyproject.toml`? I hit this issue when I accidentally had `tool.setuptools` configuration in there in addition to the configuration in `setup.py`. Deleting those sections fixed the issue for me.

> why are the files in private folder being referenced here?

That's a stack trace! Apparently that's where Python is getting its libraries from. I'm afraid I don't know the details of how exactly pip works on Mac, but it looks like some kind of temporary directory, created because you have `requires = ["setuptools==65.3.0", "wheel"]` as your build-system.